# Behavior change from Rebol 2 to Rebol 3 for empty BITSET! testing; how to test EMPTY?

Tags: rebol, bitset

In Rebol 2 you could check for an empty bitset with EMPTY?

```
>> empty? make bitset! #{00}
== true
```

In Rebol 3 *(Build 21-Feb-2011/0:44:24)* this is not the case.

```
>> empty? make bitset! #{00}
== false
```

Bug or new behavior?  Either way, how else might I do this test?  Empty bitsets of different sizes do not compare as equal in either R2 or R3:

```
>> (make bitset! #{00}) == (make bitset! #{0000})
== false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New behaviour: a bitset with >0 bits is not empty; even if it has no bits set, it still contains cleared bits.

In R3, you can `or` a given bitset with the empty bitset, to find out if the first is empty -- that is: it has no bits set -- as well:

```
>> empty? (make bitset! #{00}) or (make bitset! #{})
== true

>> empty? (make bitset! #{0000}) or (make bitset! #{})
== true
```

As a convenient shortcut, you can also just `or` with an empty `binary!`, enabling the following definition:

```
bitset-clear?: func [bitset [bitset!]] [empty? bitset or #{}]
```

Again, using your examples:

```
>> bitset-clear? make bitset! #{00}   
== true

>> bitset-clear? make bitset! #{0000}
== true
```

Comment: Gotcha.  I figured it was a bit too elementary to be a bug, but I still don't entirely grok the rationale for the change.  The fix works, and [Cyphre offered the same thing](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6293069#6293069).  *(Note again the chat linking.  Can we please get more Rebol people to realize the value of StackExchange?  Help me out, here.)*  It feels like a bit of a tenuous contract to depend on this invariant property of OR, but if it's a rule then it's a rule... :-/

Comment: The rationale might stem from a "series interpretation" of bitsets (I added a sentence towards that motivation). But then, a bitset! is not a member of the series! typeset.

Comment: I concur with @HostileFork, this is incredibly odd behavior. I had to re-read this entry several times to understand what was happening with `or` and an empty bitset. This seems excessively complex compared to the very simple and understandable behavior of EMPTY? in R2...

Answer (score 0):

Could be one of the differences in the way bitsets are constructed between R2 and R3. This still holds in R3 (A111):

```
>> eb: charset []
== make bitset! #{}

>> empty? eb
== true
```

Comment: After your beyond-the-call-of-duty work on the CSV question, I hate to point out that this isn't an answer per se.  :-)  Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Fair enough :) Clearly didn't read the question properly. Looks to be a bug, certainly to my eyes.